# How to compress a string and replace duplicates with its count using C?

Tags: c, string, compression

I have a large string char myStr="AAAABBBCCCCCCDDDEFGHHIJJ".
I shall pass this string to my string compressing function which should return me the string in below format myStr ="A4B3C6D3EFGH2IJ2"
Also, the new string replacements should happen in the same passed string only. One cannot create a temp array.

Below is my func and am not able to figure out the deletion of duplicates and replacing with its count in the same string.

```
 #include<stdio.h>
 #include<string.h>


 char* StrCompress(char myStr[])
 {
char *s = myStr;
int len = strlen(myStr);
char *in = myStr;
int count =0;
int i=0;


while(*(s) != '\0')
{
    if(*(s)==*(s+1))
    {
        count++;

        if(count == 1)
        {
            in = s;
        }
        s++;

    }
    else
    {
        //myStr[count-1]=count;
        memcpy(in+1,s+1,count);
        s=in;
        count =0;

    }
    i++;
}

return myStr;



}

int main(){

char myStr[] ="AAAABBBCCCCCEEFGIIJJJKLMNNNNOOO";

printf("Compressed String is : %s\n",StrCompress(&myStr));

return 0;

}
```

Comment: It looks like you're trying to perform a [run-length-encoding (RLE)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding), but with the count+data tuple reversed. Is that correct? Also, we can assume your string never has digits, since they would completely hose your algorithm?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A slightly modified version:

```
char* StrCompress(char myStr[])
{
  char *s, *in;
  for (s = myStr, in = myStr; *s; s++) {
    int count = 1;
    in[0] = s[0]; in++;
    while (s[0] == s[1]) {
      count++;
      s++;
    }   
    if (count > 1) {
      int len = sprintf(in, "%d", count);
      in += len;
    }   
  }
  in[0] = 0;
  return myStr;
}
```

Additionally, you should not use the address of operator when calling with an array name:

```
StrCompress(myStr); // not StrCompress(&myStr)
```

If you are assuming that a character can't repeat more then 9 times, then you can use `in[0] = '0' + count` instead of the `sprintf` stuff:

```
if (count > 1) {
  in[0] = '0' + count;
  in++;
}
```

Comment: oops, didnt notice... Now i like your answer more.. :)

Comment: @faezshingeri, updated the multi-digit version to remove the buffer

Comment: For input `AAAABBBCCCCCEEFGIIJJJKLMNNNNO`, I get `A4B3C5E2FGI2J3KLMN4OJKLMNNNNO`. The final `N` is not compressed.

Comment: @perreal Is the other way round possible within the same array? or we SHOULD use another array?
eg: A4B3DFG2 changed to AAAABBBDFGG

Comment: @faezshingeri, it could be possible but the array should have enough room to accommodate the expanded version. You could start expanding from the end of the string but first calculating the size of the expanded version.

Comment: There's an interesting feature of the stated problem, vs a similar problem in "cracking the coding interview". In the later, they want you to compress "aabbb" into "a1b2". The reason that is interesting is `sprintf(in, "%d", count)` is actually printing `1\0`, so it can only work for compression of 2 or more, otherwise a temporary buffer to print the integer into is needed.

Comment: As @Alun points out, this solution is buggy, and the version with the extra buffer was correct. Inputs with characters of run-length two (such as "AABBBCCA" will only output A2, since sprintf copies 1\0 to `in`, the pointer `*s` think it's hit the end of the string and immediately exits the for loop.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include<stdio.h>

char* StrCompress(char myStr[])
{
    char *s = myStr;
    char *r, *p;
    int count, i;

    while (*s)
    {
        /*initially only 1 character of a kind is present*/
        count = 1;

        /*we check whether current character matches the next one*/
        while (*s && *s == *(s+1))
        {
            /*if yes,then increase the count due to the match 
            and increment the string pointer to next */
            count++;
            s++;
        }

        if (count > 1) /*if more than one character of a kind is present*/
        {
            /*assign the value of count to second occurence of a particular character*/
            *(s - count + 2) = count + '0';

            /*delete all other occurences except the first one and second one using array shift*/
            for (i = 0; i < count - 2; i++)
            {
                p = s + 1;
                r = s;

                while (*r)
                    *r++ = *p++;

                s--;
            }
        }
        s++;
    }

    return myStr;
}

int main()
{
    char myStr[] = "AAAABBBCCCCCCDDDEFGHHIJJ";

    printf("Compressed String is : %s\n", StrCompress(myStr));

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String...args) {
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the String:");
    String str=sc.next();
    int count=1;
    for(int i=0;i<str.length()-1;i++) {
        Character ch1=str.charAt(i);
        Character ch2=str.charAt(i+1);
        if(ch1.equals(ch2)) {
            count++;
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.print((char)(str.charAt(i)));
            if(count>1) {
                System.out.print(count);
            }
            count=1;
        }
        if(i==(str.length()-2)) 
        {
            if(ch1.equals(ch2))
            {System.out.print(ch1+""+count);}
            else {System.out.print(ch2);}
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide some detail for further information.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String compress(String str) {
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    int i = 0;
    int count = 0;
    while(i < str.length() - 1) {
        count++;
        if (str.charAt(i) != str.charAt(i + 1)) {
            result.append(str.charAt(i)).append(count);
            count = 0;
        }
        i++;
    }
    result.append(str.charAt(i)).append(count + 1);
    return result.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.print("enter the string");
    String s=(new Scanner(System.in)).nextLine();
    String s2=new String("");
    int count=0;

    for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++)
    {
        count=1;



        s2=s2+(s.charAt(i));

        while(i+1<s.length() && s.charAt(i+1)==s.charAt(i)  )
        {
            count++;

            i++;

        }

        s2=s2.concat(count+"");

        }

        System.out.print(s2);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is another implementation in case anyone needs it. FYI, this method is called run-length encoding

```
#include <iostream>

void CompressString (std::string str)
{
    //count will keep track of the number of occurences of any given character
    unsigned int count = 1;

    //new string to store the values from the original string
    std::string str2 = "";

    //store the first letter of the string initially
    char ch = str[0];

    //run a loop from the second character of the string since first character if stored in "ch"
    for (unsigned int i = 1; i < str.length(); i++)
    {
        if (str[i] == ch)
            count++;
        else
        {
            str2 = str2 + ch + std::to_string (count);
            ch = str[i];
            count = 1;
        }
    }

    //for cases like aabbb
    str2 = str2 + ch + std::to_string (count);

    //check if after compression, the length of the string reduces or not
    if (str.length() > str2.length())
        std::cout << str2 << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << str << std::endl;
}

int main ()
{
    std::cout << "Enter a string to compress: ";
    std::string str;
    getline (std::cin, str);

    std::cout << "Compressed string is: ";
    CompressString (str);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another inplace java program . We can use StringBuilder instead of string

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String a = "aaabbccaaaddj";


        for(int i=0;i<a.length();i++){
            int c=i+1;
            int duplicateCharCount=1;
            while(c<a.length()&&a.charAt(c)==a.charAt(i)){
                ++c;
                ++duplicateCharCount;
            }

                a=a.substring(0,i+1)+duplicateCharCount+a.substring(i+duplicateCharCount);
                i++;


        }
        System.out.println(a);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class StringCompression {
    public static String compress(String str) {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        int i;
        int count = 0;
        for(i=0; i< str.length() - 1;i++,count++) {
            if (str.charAt(i) != str.charAt(i + 1)) {
                result.append(str.charAt(i)).append(count);
                count = 0;
            }
        }

        result.append(str.charAt(i)).append(count);
        return result.toString();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String string = "aaassssdddaaaggghhhfgreeeeeeedrrrrr";
        String x= compress(string);
        System.err.println(x);
    }
}
```

Comment: Avoid code only answers. Add some information as to how it answers the question, why the problem was there in the first place or something.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

char* compress(char* str);

int main(){
  clrscr();
  char str[1000];
  scanf("%[^\n]s", str);
  char* s = compress(str);
  printf("\n%s", s);
  getch();
  return 0;
}

char* compress(char* str){
 char* s = str;
 int count = 1;
 char str2[1000] = "\0";
 char* n = str2;
 while(*(s) != '\0'){
    if(count == 1){
      *n = *s;
      n++;
    }
    if(*(s) == *(s+1)){
      count++;
      s++;
    }
    else{
     *n = '0' + count;
     n++;
     count = 1;
     s++;
    }
}
 return str2;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited short-term help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution with ES6:

```
    // aaeezaa : a4e2z1
    function compressString(str) {
        const obj = {};
        const sortedArr = [...str].sort();

        for(i = 0; i<sortedArr.length; i++) {
            let c = 1;

            while((sortedArr[i] === sortedArr[i+1]) && sortedArr[i+1]) {
                c++;
                i++;
            }

            obj[sortedArr[i]] = c;
        }

        return Object.keys(obj).reduce((compressedStr, k) => compressedStr + k + obj[k], '');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I made two assumptions and wrote this code,

1. we have space double the size of string which we are encoding. i.e., suppose we are encoding "ab", then the space space allotted should be at-least 4 bytes.
2. continuous streak of alphabets can be max 999. if there is a chance that there can be 1000 same characters in adjacent positions then, we have to increase "count_str" char array size accordingly.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>

    char *compress(char *input)  {

        int i = 0;

        int count = 1;

        int k = 0;

        int j = 0;

        int len = 0; 

        int digits_in_count = 0;

        char count_str[3];

        int m = 0;

        for(i = 0; i < strlen(input); i++) {

            j = i+1;

            m = 0;

            count = 1;

            len = strlen(input);

            printf("\niteration: %d, string = %s",i, input);

            while((input[j] != '\0') && (input[j] == input[i])) {
                count++;
                j++;
            }

            sprintf(count_str, "%d", count);

            digits_in_count = strlen(count_str);

            //this means we have reaced last alphabet in the string
            if(input[j] == '\0' && count == 1) {

                k = k+1;
                goto count_append;

            }

            input[k++] =  input[i];

            // we are assuming that we have enough space in the end, to move string.
            // we are memmove for remaining portion of the string.
            // if the string is "aaab", then we have to move 'b' one step ahead 
            // and it will look like "aab", later in the end we are adding count,
            // and making it as "a3b".
            // if the string is "ab", then we have to move 'b' one step away,
            // to make space for adding 'count'.
            // and the new string after memmove will looklike "abb",
            // in the end we are adding count and making it as "a1b"
            // memmove will not hit for last character in the string, because there
            // is already enough space for appending 'count'.
            memmove((input+i+digits_in_count+1) , input+j, len-j+1);

            i = i+digits_in_count;

            count_append:
            {
                while(digits_in_count) {

                    input[k++] =  *(count_str+m);

                    m = m+1;
                    digits_in_count--;

                }
            }

        }   

        return input;

    }

    void main()
    {
        char arr[50] = "aaab";
        printf("\n%s\n", compress(arr));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void gen_compressed_str(string str){ 
        int len = str.length(); 
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) { 
  
        int count = 1; 
        while (i < len - 1 && str[i] == str[i + 1]) { 
            count++; 
            i++; 
        }
        if (count == 1){
          cout << str[i];
        }
        else{
          cout << str[i]<<count;
        }
         
    } 
    cout<<endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void stringCompression(char a[]) {
    int i, count=1,j=0;
    for(i=0;a[i]!='\0';i++){
        if(a[i]==a[i+1]){
            count++;
        }
        else if(a[i]!=a[i+1]){
            if(count>1){
                a[j++]=a[i];
                a[j++]=(char)(48+count);
            }
            else if(count==1){
                a[j++]=a[i];
            }
            count=1;
        }
    }
    a[j]='\0';
}
```

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.

Comment: @DCCoder is right. And this is even more important when answering a seven year old question with twelve existing answers, including an accepted answer. What sets your approach apart from other answers? What new information are you contributing? Why should a reader try this approach instead of the others?